# Ubuntu - SmartFoxServer - Check program is running

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.10

I am wanting to run SmartFox Server on my Ubuntu 8.10 Intrepid server

default port is 9339

I cant telnet localhost 9339 as it says connection reused

UFW is off as status shows not loaded

So I want to:

1. Check that the SMARTFOX is loaded - i do ./sfs start and it says loaded
2. Check why I cant access localy via telnet to the 9339 port.

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check to see if SmartFoxServer is running. Note that I have never used SmartFox, so I don't know the exact name that you'll be looking for, but I'm assuming that it will have "smartfox" or "sfs" somewhere in it:

```
ps -ef | egrep -i "[s]martfox|[s]fs"
```

If it is running, that command should output some information on the process. (The square brackets in the regular expression make sure that this command does not find itself in the process listing).

Now, check to see if it's attached to a port:

```
lsof -i :9339
```

If SmartFox is running, you should get some output that ends with ":9339 (LISTEN)"

So, now we've checked if the process is running or listening. The last thing to check is if there is a firewall that is blocking it from being accessed. Check to see if your firewall is enabled, and if so, what its settings are. I'm assuming that you would be using the default firewall for Ubuntu, [`ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Uncomplicated_Firewall_ufw):

```
sudo ufw status
```

If the firewall is enabled, you should see some settings; otherwise, it should tell you that the firewall is not loaded.

If it is enabled, you can try allowing the port in question:

```
sudo ufw allow 9339
```

**edit**: oops, I hadn't noticed that you said that UFW is off. Sorry for assuming you hadn't checked that yet.

Comment: Brian thank you for the thorough reply:

I tried the ps command (like that one, what i have been searching for)
output

I did ps -A

Couldnt see any SFS related processs open - and nothing that looked familiaer - cant find what it should be in docs either

Need to locate logs of SFS to check

Comment: I think the process name is actually 'wrapper' which isn't entirely helpful - this answer is fantastic but the sfs status command is the one you really need.

This answer cracks the "is it bound to the right port" question nicely though.

Answer (score 1):

./sfs status will indicate whether sfs is running. Also, check wrapper_MMDDYY.log in logs directory.

You could also ./sfs console.